# Unable redirect view inside ErrorViewResolver on Spring Boot 1.5.20.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am experimenting with ErrorViewResolver, trying to redirect view from the ModelAndView, but it keeps shows 404 http status error. The Spring Boot version I am using is 1.5.20.RELEASE. While I downgrade the version to 1.5.1x.RELEASE or upgrade to 2.x, it is redirected successfully.

Here's sample code:

```java
@Component
public class MyErrorResolveView implements ErrorViewResolver {
    @Override
    public ModelAndView resolveErrorView(HttpServletRequest request, HttpStatus status, Map<String, Object> model) {
        // return new ModelAndView("test"); // this work fine
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/page"); 
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/pages/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```

Controller

```java
 @GetMapping(value =  {"/page"})
 public ModelAndView page() {
    return new ModelAndView("test");
 }
```

Spring Security:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().disable().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
}
```

JSP location: src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages/test.jsp

Run with bootRun, try to access http://localhost:8080/notExist, expected to see "test" page, but actual see HTTP ERROR 404 page.

- Spring Boot 1.5.20.RELEASE
- java 1.8
- Gradle 5.2.1

I am not sure is there any configuration I missed, or it is a bug/feature for Spring Boot 1.5.20.RELEASE?

Comment: have you added the jasper dependency for jsp?. Also does the controller class for `page()` has another mapping?

Comment: yes I have added jasper in my Gradle dependency, and only one controller and one  request mapping in my entire site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Spring Boot 1.5.20.RELEASE` depends on `tomcat-embed-core 8.5.39` and the tomcat version has some breaking changes. Try to use old `tomcat-embed-core` version.

Comment: As mentioned, I downgrade Spring Boot to 1.5.19.RELEASE as well as spring-boot-starter-tomcat to 1.5.19.RELEASE, it resolves the issue. But if I only change the starter tomcat to 1.5.19.RELEASE which depends on tomcat-embed-core 8.5.37, the issue still remain.

Comment: I am sure this issue was caused by `tomcat-embed-core 8.5.39`. Use `gradle dependencies` to check which version of  `tomcat-embed-core` you are using.

Comment: Sample Project: https://github.com/phstudy/springboot-1.5.20-redirect-test

Comment: You're right. Only `tomcat-embed-core 8.5.39` gets thing breakdown, whereas 8.5.38 or 8.5.40 works correctly. I found similar disaster also caused from 8.5.39 here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16486.